# Why can't we embed a video in a question or answer?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support

Or maybe we can and I just don't know how to do it? Sometimes it's easier to display a video of gameplay and since I understand you don't want code, why not just remove the possibility of putting code here.

I've recorded a demo of the scene:

> [www.youtube.com/watch?v=PF_UzoOXD0E](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PF_UzoOXD0E)

Here's the research so far:

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/56711/how-to-make-my-jme3-character-walk-over-slopes-and-stairs-instead-of-sliding

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782375/how-to-improve-character-control-for-my-3d-game/16988342?noredirect=1#comment24704812_16988342

Comment: "*I understand you don't want code*" You clearly misunderstood the difference between "not wanting any code" and "not wanting a *[ridiculous wall of code](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/56711/how-to-make-my-jme3-character-walk-over-slopes-and-stairs-instead-of-sliding)*."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the problem is reasonably scoped (and truly needs a video to explain it), then that video ought to be extremely short.  And space is a concern, so give it high compression and no sound.

**Make a gif!**  It sure helps make [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/57087/line-draw-on-even-q-vertical-flat-topped-hex-grid/57098) more answerable.

Of course, the best gif in the world won't save an otherwise broken question.

"WHAT'S WRONG WITH MY RAGDOLL PHYSICS?"
"See my video.  What's wrong?  Thanks in advance."

[image]

Comment: Physics don't operate the same in Sparta. Without the GIF I wouldn't have known enough to answer.

Answer (score 7):

Embedded videos are essentially pretty-looking links, susceptible to [undesirable link rot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Stack Exchange sites protect images from link rot when uploaded using the [image: "Add Image"-button] *Add Image* button (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>): a separate copy is uploaded to `https://i.stack.imgur.com/` [in partnership with imgur](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90342/any-details-about-stack-imgur-com).  This is currently not possible for videos, likely because they tend to be huge in comparison.

Comment: Excellent answer.

Comment: `Images are protected from link rot by StackExchange sites.` Great!  Why then is it that I continue to find relatively recent questions lacking images, such as [this one](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/56589/texture-coordinate-discontinuity-with-mipmaps-creates-seams)?

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer Sorry, I should have been more specific. [That question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/56589/texture-coordinate-discontinuity-with-mipmaps-creates-seams)'s images were uploaded to a different site and only linked here. One should use the *Add Image* button (or press *Ctrl + g*) to upload images, as they go to StackExchange's dedicated `http://i.stack.imgur.com/` site. I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: Hm, really, adding images in any other way should be disallowed then because it's counterintuitive for SE as a knowledgebase when links break. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer No problem. I found [a Meta SE question requesting that same thing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231613/disallow-new-embedded-images-from-hosts-other-than-the-se-imgur-account).

Comment: Are `*.webm`'s supported on this site?

Comment: Im a little confused, Stack Exchange at least partially supports videos, as this is no problem on Arqade.

Comment: @Timelord64 Like using "password" as your password, it only becomes a problem when it becomes a problem. An external video host can take down videos for reasons we don't control, thereby rendering our posts useless. I'd rather not put the fate of our preserved knowledge in someone else's hands without a strict contract, especially someone [as trigger-happy as YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zVqFAMOtwaI).